# Embed filtered report print preview in form/subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

[Version used : Access 2019]

My `MainForm` contains :

```
ComboBox "cb_choice_clientID"  ---> user selected ID for Table "Clients"
SubForm "sf_previewPanel"      ---> I want to preview directly in "MainForm"
```

**Based on the `clientID` chosen by the user, I want to directly preview in `sf_previewPanel` the report `myReport` filtered for that `clientID`.**

---

**What I can already do :**

1) Open the filtered `myReport` in a new tab/window in `Print Preview` using a WHERE condition named `sSQL` below :

```
Private Sub cb_choice_clientID_AfterUpdate()
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = IIf(IsNull(Me.cb_choice_clientID), "", "clientID=" & Me.cb_choice_clientID)
    DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewPreview, "", sSQL, acNormal
End Sub
```

---> But I want to preview the filtered report directly in `MainForm`...

2) View unfiltered `myReport` in `Report View` directly in the subform `sf_previewPanel` :

```
Me.sf_previewPanel.SourceObject = "Report.myReport"
```

---> But I can't get a `Print Preview` there, and I can't find a way to apply my filter to the report without digging in the report itself or the query behind it through VBA, which is a pain...

---

**My question** : is it possible to mix my two approaches in order to preview `myReport` filtered by `sSQL` WHERE condition directly in `MainForm` (through a subform or whatever) ?

**Optional question 1** : is it possible to get a `Print Preview` instead of a `Report View` ?

**Optional bonus** : is it possible with simple code which doesn't dive in recordsets ? ;-)

Thanks for any answer or help to precise my question !

---

---

[EDIT : Answer step 1]

As @RicardoDiaz said in a comment, the functionality is native to Access : I just had to "drag and drop" `myReport` in `MainForm` to create a subreport, and link `Master Fields` and `Child Fields` together.

Yet, using master/child relationship, I can't find how to display the report as `Print Preview`, despite the setting being applied to `myReport` as default view. Any idea why / how to fix ?

Comment: The AfterUpdate event you're attaching to the combo is native to forms/subforms when you link the main and secondary fields. And instead of using a subform which can't be inserted in print preview in a main form, you could create a report and insert it as a subreport in the main field.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks, helped a lot ! Now the filter is applied through master/child relationship. Edited my question to add that partial answer. Yet, I can't display the subreport in `Print Preview`. Any idea why ?

Comment: What’s the purpose of having it in print preview? AFAIK, it’s not possible, but I can be wrong

Comment: @RicardoDiaz My `MainForm` allows me to change the contents of `myReport`, and I noticed that the report rendering is faulty in Report View (alignments, etc.), while Print Preview is clean and corresponds to the exact PDF which is the end goal. The idea of the subreport is to preview the future PDF and correct typos if necessary (Rich Text involved). So far, didn't find any mention of Print View in subreports either...

Comment: It's weird that the print preview doesn't correspond to the report layout. Hard to tell without seeing it